# Get data from 4 tables who share a common field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this structure,

tables

```
employees

id

name
_______________________
entrance

id_employees

day

hour
_______________________
break

id_employees

day

hour
_______________________
break_end

id_employees

day

hour
_______________________
exit

id_employees

day

hour
```

So I need to list the register for every employee where "id_employees" equals "id" of the employees table, i have managed to do it on two tables   but nothing works to  link them all, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be having problems because all your tables have columns with the same name, and they will overwrite each other in an output array in your software. You can work around that by using column aliases:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, 
       ee.day AS entrance_day, ee.hour AS entrance_hour,
       b.day AS break_day, b.hour AS break_hour,
       be.day AS break_end_day, be.hour AS break_end_hour,
       ex.day AS exit_day, ex.hour AS exit_hour
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN entrance ee ON ee.id_employees = e.id
LEFT JOIN break b ON b.id_employees = e.id
LEFT JOIN break_end be ON be.id_employees = e.id
LEFT JOIN exit ex ON ex.id_employees = e.id
```

Note that you need to use `LEFT JOIN` in case an employee doesn't have a break on a given day. Using an `INNER JOIN` in that case would result in no row in the output for those employees.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely solution is via a left join though you may need to alias common column names to distinguish them.
The basis of the query to do this would be:

```
SELECT e.*,b.*,be.*,e.* FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN break b ON e.id = b.id_employees
LEFT JOIN break_end br ON e.id = b.id_employees
LEFT JOIN exit ON e.id = id_employees
```

Because you have similar column names in multiple tables,you will have to be more specific on the SELECT clause to differentiate more easily the different columns you need

like:

```
SELECT e.id, 
       b.day as break_day, 
       b.hour as break_hour, 
       br.day as break_end_day, 
       br.hour as break_end_hour, 
       ...
```

And so forth